# Possible loss of method on basic objects when using templated declaration

Tags: c++, templates, casting, cout

This is an application of the answer in this thread..
[How do I return the largest type in a list of types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803814/how-do-i-return-the-largest-type-in-a-list-of-types/22390396#22390396)

where a template allows one to define a type which is the max of two objects.

I somehow lose the method of int by the look of the error message of the compiler.

Heres is a code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A>
struct givenType {
    typedef A type;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct largestType {
    typedef typename givenType<std::conditional<sizeof(A) <= sizeof(B), B, A         >>::type type;
};


template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Alpha {
public:
    typedef typename largestType<T1,T2>::type bigT3;
    Alpha() {};

    bigT3 answer(void) {
        bigT3 t;
        return t;
    }

    void tryCout(void) {
        std::cout << answer() << std::endl;
    }

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Alpha<int,int> a;
    a.tryCout();
    return 0;
}
```

along with the following error:

error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::conditional<_Test,_Ty1,_Ty2>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) with

```
[
    _Test=true,
    _Ty1=int,
    _Ty2=int
]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send the whole `std::conditional` struct to `std::cout` (Big3 is now same as `std::conditional` with a type typedef of `int`).

`std::conditional` gives you the selected type through its typedef `type`. You should use that.

```
typename std::conditional<sizeof(A) <= sizeof(B), B, A>::type
                                                         ^^^^
```

so the whole thing should look like

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct largestType {
    typedef typename givenType<
                       typename 
                       std::conditional<
                         sizeof(A) <= sizeof(B)
                         , B
                         , A
                       >::type // You missed this type
                     >::type type;
};
```

---

However you don't really need the `givenType` template struct. you can just use the one from `conditional`

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct largestType {
    typedef typename 
              std::conditional<
                sizeof(A) <= sizeof(B)
                , B
                , A
              >::type type;
};
```

OR just

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Alpha {
public:
    typedef typename 
              std::conditional<
                sizeof(T1) <= sizeof(T2)
                , T2
                , T1
              >::type bigT3;
```

Comment: Thank you, can't upvote for lack of reputation but works well.  Notice the double typename as well required when using nested templates.

Comment: @user3417339 Yes you need 'typename' there. however it seemed you already knew that since you are using it properly in the other places. That's why i didn't emphasize it more. you can't upvote but you can still accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The error about `<<` could very well be due to having nested openings of `<>` next to each other somewhere, in (older?) C++ compilers that translates into the left shift operator, complete nonsense in that context (and thus source of incomprehensible error messsages). Replace `<<` with `< <` (space in between).